# Sharing iCloud data between two apps

Tags: iphone, core-data, share, icloud

I'm wanted find more information regarding this.

I intend to make an app right now with iCloud core data store.  And i wish to share that with another app (different bundle Identifier) is it possible? Obviously, i shall include the iCloud capabilities in another app as well ,but with the AppIDs and all, it seems questionable.

Another question if I may, I am planning to use iCloud sync for CoreData and a plist File. From what I know, usually apps take one of the approach, but I  needed to sync core data as it is intended, and use a small plist file, which isn't a settings file. Is this a bad way ? or should i just use one of the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The identifier used for iCloud storage is different from the bundle identifer used for the app, so, yes, it's entirely possible
2. Yes. You can sync Core Data, "documents" *and* key-values pairs using iCloud in the same app

All else being equal, I think you'd be better putting your plist into your Core Data model (less code).

Comment: Agreed.  If your data requirements already have you using Core Data then **ALL** data should be in Core Data.  Less confusion, more consistency, more management code.

Comment: Could you expand on some basic know how to access same iCloud docs with two potentially different Apps?

Comment: There's an iCloud identifier in your entitlements file. If it's the same in both apps you'll be able to access the same data/documents. That's it.