# iCloud - access data at the same time

Tags: ios, icloud, inventory

For an iOS game we're currently exploring the use of iCloud to store user inventory. We want to be able to transfer such inventory assets between multiple apps, or better, make them available for usage within multiple apps.

this [Sharing iCloud data between two apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882682/sharing-icloud-data-between-two-apps) thread states that it's possible to access the same iCloud storage from multiple apps.

But in such a case, questions of concurrency arise. How can one manage the case that a user uses two devices at the same time for example to sell the same inventory item? Can locks somehow be put in place? Or is iCloud the wrong technology choice for sharing inventory among apps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to make the transaction on the server-side and push the change to all clients to make this reliable (and without exploits).

iCloud has two failings in this regard: you have no control over the server and it's not "real time" -- sometimes it "batches" changes, and you have no say over when this happens.

I think this means you need a technology other than iCloud.

Comment: thank you for your assessment. Do you see some apple technology that could provide such functionality, or do we need to go with a custom backend for this?

Comment: I think you need something non-Apple. There are a bunch of services (Heroku, Cloudbase.io, Parse) so you don't have to start completely from scratch.