# iOS Storage across Developers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to create an integration between my app and apps by another developer.  There are several ways to store data for an app, some that allow only your app to access it, some that allow other apps by the same developer to access it.  But is there an iOS API that allows you store data publicly on the device so that any other app can access it? This data is not secure and cannot be used maliciously.

Comment: There is no way to share data between developers directly on the device. Your options are to store the data on the network somewhere or use URLs to pass the data between apps

Comment: If you can coordinate with the other developer you can use the iCloud to share data. If the two apps have the same iCloud identifier in their entitlements they can write/read files in the same space. Btw this question has been asked again you can see relevant and more complete answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882682/sharing-icloud-data-between-two-apps and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882682/sharing-icloud-data-between-two-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not work for your specific needs, but note you can share documents between apps using [UISupportsDocumentBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app/setting_up_a_document_browser_app). See also [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW37).

> UISupportsDocumentBrowser (Boolean - iOS) Specifies that the app is a document-based app and uses the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class.
>
> If this key is set to YES, the user can set the document browser’s default save location in Settings. Additionally, the local file provider grants access to all the documents in the app’s Documents directory. These documents appear in the Files app, and in a Document Browser. Users can open and edit these document in place.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 11 and later.

Answer (score -1):

This would violate iOS security policies and is therefore not possible on device. The only way to enable this is on a jailbroken device.